# JS : Getting image id using onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i  have 4 images  in my document , 1 at the top and three at the bottom  now what i want when i hover over any of the bottom 3 images i get its  id and replace the above image with this  image using onmouseover ,  like this

```
 <script >
   function chanageimg(id)// here i want  to pass hovered image  src 
      {
          document.getElementById("top_image").src=id;

      }
   </script>

 <div id="top" >
   <img src="top.jpg"  id="top_image" />
 </div>

 //here is the  bottom image , 
<div class ="floats one">
  <img src="img1.jpg"  id="img1"  onmouseover="changeimg()" />
</div>
```

how do i get its src to be passed in aboce function  . i dont want to use Jquery . here as its for learning purpose

Comment: onmouseover="changeimg(this.id)"

Comment: and how will it be passed in above parameter ?

Comment: if you make my change, your code should work as written.

Comment: You want to pass the image src or the image id? You're saying src but your code says id. Which is it?

Comment: if you can explain  a bit about working of 'this' in  this scenario that will be great favour  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small change to your HTML:

```
<img src="img1.jpg"  id="img1"  onmouseover="changeimg(this.id)" />
```

`this` is the image being moused over, and `this.id` is the parameter you want to pass to your function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function changeimg(e), use `e.target.id` to get the id. If you do this, you don't need to add this.id to every `onmouseover=""` in your images. Just use `onmouseover="changeimg"`.

Comment: nope. this==window inside the changeimg() function (as wired). you would have to assign changeimg as an event handler for that to work (notice the one-off inline handler that dispatches changeimg)...

Answer (score 1):

To change the image you  have to change the `src`

```
<img id="img-top"  src="">
<img src="img1.jpg" onmouseover="changeimg(this.src)">

function changeimg(src){
    document.getElementById("top_image").src = src;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/dW3Zk/)**